# io.write Printing the same thing every time?

Tags: io, lua

I'm extremely new to lua and programming in general, and am currently making a basic program to get familiar with if/else/elseif and i/o.

Basically, it asks if you are a boy or girl, then prints what you are accordingly.

Although, I have a problem in that every time i run the program, it will always print that you are a boy.

Sorry if I'm being an idiot, any help is appreciated!

code is as follows;

```
io.write("Hello, are you a boy or a girl?\n")
answer = io.read()
if answer == "boy" or "Boy" then
io.write("Oh, so you're a boy, huh?")
elseif answer == "girl" or "Girl" then
io.write("Oh, so you're a girl, huh?")
else
io.write("Wow, i've never heard of an "..answer.." before!\n")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
io.write("Hello, are you a boy or a girl?\n")

answer = io.read()

if answer == "boy" or answer == "Boy" then
  io.write("Oh, so you're a boy, huh?")
elseif answer == "girl" or answer == "Girl" then
  io.write("Oh, so you're a girl, huh?")
else
  io.write("Wow, i've never heard of an "..answer.." before!\n")
end
```

---

## Explanation

[Docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.4) says:

> The disjunction operator or returns its first argument if this value is different from nil and false; otherwise, or returns its second argument.

Steps if answer == "girl":

1. `answer == "boy" or "Boy"`
2. `false or "Boy"`
3. `"Boy"`
4. String is treated as true -> execute if

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```
if answer == "boy" or "Boy" then
```

With this:

```
if answer == "boy" or answer == "Boy" then
```

And similar for the other case.